# In Google Sheets, how do I search for a value in lists in multiple sheets, and return a result if there is at least one match?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, vlookup

I have a sheet with a list of company names in column A - some of these company names are present within sheets of different users, who have a tickbox within a column beside these companies.

I want to have a column in my sheet which would tell me whether this company is ticked within one of the user's sheets and if so, put the user's name in the cell next to it. If not, it can remain blank. The likelihood at this time that the tickbox is TRUE for the same company in two different sheets is negligible.

In the sample sheet below, I've used the following formula in cell B2:

```
=ifs(vlookup(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$11,2,false)=TRUE,"Sam",vlookup(A2,Sheet3!$A$2:$B$11,2,false)=TRUE,"Nick",vlookup(A2,Sheet4!$A$2:$B$11,2,false)=TRUE,"Mike")
```

It works for the first two conditions, but then it cannot seem to work with the third logical pair. Note that the sample sheet below uses the vlookup across tabs, the actual sheet will be using importrange, but I don't think it should make a difference.

What could be wrong?

Sample sheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18IJ8pb024NWQt6HrlGN1wfhZMXLPdmYHT5v8hFsW3Ho/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A More General Problem

To make this more general so others find it useful (which is the whole point of StackOverflow), the general problem can be rephrased as

> "How do I search for a value in lists in multiple sheets, and return a
> result if there is at least one match?"

Generally, when using `VLOOKUP()`, `QUERY()`, or other matching functions, you have to account for any errors through non-matches.  Those "move" outwards into the outer functions and can eventually be the reported result, unless explicitly handled. Sometimes, this is less obvious when you sometimes get answers but that's because the outer functions have ignored or not evaluated the matching function.

Therefore, always consider what happens if the matching function returns a `N/A` and explicitly handle it.

### Your Example

In your case, `IFS()` is simply raising an error whenever `VLOOKUP()` does not match.  However, since `IFS()` returns the first condition that matches, from left to right in the formula, it doesn't always get around to evaluating one of the non-matching `VLOOKUP()`s which is why you see it works sometimes.

So, you should explicitly handle the errors with e.g. `IFERROR()`

My approach was to avoid lookup functions, and just filter the list by those that had filled checkboxes, and then count the occurrence of interest ("Company 1", "Company 2", ...) using `COUNTIF()`. If the counted total is 1, we have a match, so grab that entry as an element in an array. Otherwise, leave an empty value.

At this point, you could drop the empty elements, and take the first non-empty element (or return a blank), but I opted to list out all of the names.

To get rid of the blanks, I use `QUERY()` and then `JOIN()` to make a list of each name. In the case, where nothing matched, and my array was empty, I simply wrap everything in one `IFERROR()`.

```
=IFERROR(JOIN(", ",QUERY(TRANSPOSE({IF(COUNTIF(FILTER(Sam!A:A,Sam!B:B=TRUE),A2)=1,"Sam",""),IF(COUNTIF(FILTER(Nick!A:A,Nick!B:B=TRUE),A2)=1,"Nick",""),IF(COUNTIF(FILTER(Mike!A:A,Mike!B:B=TRUE),A2)=1,"Mike","")}),"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL",0)),"")
```

I found it convenient for your example to rename "Sheet2" as "Sam", "Sheet3" as "Nick", "Sheet4" as "Mike", which is what I think was your original meaning.

The formula can be easily modified to show just the first matching result.

Comment: Thank you. I've taken your advice and named the question so that other users can find the question more easily. My mistake for keeping it vague. Your solution has worked for me.

Comment: Good to hear! If the answer was useful, please mark it as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, QUERY({
 QUERY(Sheet2!A2:B, "select A,B,'Sam'"); 
 QUERY(Sheet3!A2:B, "select A,B,'Nick'"); 
 QUERY(Sheet4!A2:B, "select A,B,'Mike'")}, 
 "where Col2=TRUE"), 3, )))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this solution has worked perfectly for me as well.